# I want make distance matrix using google api

Tags: python, distance-matrix

I am trying to use the Google API using Python.
The distance matrix I'm going to make looks like this:

[image: Figure 1]

I want to find the navigation from A to B, C, D, E
It's not an Euclidean distance.
The data I have is the address and coordinates (latitude and longitude) of each point.

I want to tabulate the distance and time as shown in the figure, as if I did directions on Google Maps (https://www.google.com/maps).

I don't even dare to start yet.
What data should I refer to or search for?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I getting it right you want to create a first dataset of points' coordinates in order to then calculate the distances between them and the time needed for the trips.

I suggest you to create something like the following:

[image]

Please, notice that the coordinates are in GPS format. You that have to manage them as a geodataframe in order to calculate distances and times.

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer
I saw it late

I found the answer by loading json using another map api because google map was not available in the area I was trying to do.

Comment: No problem. If the reply answers anyway your question, would you condider to accept it?
Thanks